# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Занятия в «Школе герметизации» — это возможность выстроить конструктивный диалог и полезное взаимодействие между потребителем и компанией-поставщиком (,) с целью повышения уровня промышленной безопасности и операционной эффективности производства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая здесь не нужна.